# Различные фикстуры unit тесты yii1

Tags: php, yii, юнит-тесты, phpunit

В документации есть следующий пример использования фикстур

```
class CommentTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public $fixtures=array(
        'posts'=>'Post',
        'comments'=>'Comment',
    );

    …
}
```

можно еще использовать фикстуры без ActiveRecord таким образом 'post' => ':post'.
Я хочу сделать чтобы в разных тестах использовались разные фикстуры, например чтобы когда я тестирую Post модель, то в базу заливались фикстуры post.php, а когда я тестирую класс например Author, чтобы в таблицу с post заливались post_for_author.php
Пробовал сделать так

```
class CommentTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public $fixtures=array(
        'posts_for_author'=>'Post',
        'comments'=>'Comment',
    );

    …
}
```

и так 'posts_for_author'=>':post',
не работает. Как сделать, чтобы работало?
Пример привел упрощенный, я понимаю что unit тесты не должны быть зависимы от множества фикстур, что тестировать нужно функционал класса, но есть необходимость, сделать так как описал выше.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй изолированные фикстуры:

application/tests/unit:

```
class CommentTest extends IsolatedFixtureDbTestCase {
    public $fixtures=array(
        'posts_for_author'=>'Post',
        'comments'=>'Comment',
    );
    ...
}
```

Путь к фикстурам подгружается при начале нового теста в зависимости от имени теста. По окончанию теста возвращается изначальное значение пути.

application/tests:

```
abstract class IsolatedFixtureDbTestCase extends CDbTestCase
{
    private $basePathOld = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $fixturePath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.tests.fixtures.' . get_class($this));
        if (is_dir($fixturePath)) {
            $this->basePathOld = $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath;
            $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath = $fixturePath;
        }
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        if (null !== $this->basePathOld) {
            $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath = $this->basePathOld;
        }
    }
}
```

После этого в директории application/tests/fixtures можешь создать папку с названием класса CommentTest и в неё положить соответствующие фикстуры